# changing mapset in cmd

Tags: grass-gis

can anyone suggest me for changing mapset from current location using command prompt.I have compiled the grass gis 6.4.4 and when ever i want to use the commands every time i am opening gui and setting the mapset and location. without starting grass gui, i want to run my module. is it possible? And i have one more query regarding the mapset.my module is every time it is looking for same mapset and i have to load that only, but i want to test it for other data of different region. even if i change mapset and location in gui , libgrassgis-dll missing it is showing and not working.without grass gui i want to run it.may i know where the problem is and is?

Answer (score 1):

Have you seen this command?
[g.mapset](http://grass.osgeo.org/grass64/manuals/g.mapset.html)

Answer (score 1):

You can certainly start GRASS without the gui:

```
grass64 -text
```

Furthermore, you can run GRASS in batch mode without actually "starting" the program at all. If you prepare a bash script which sets up the required environment, then you can have GRASS commands run without the GRASS interface at all.
Full details in the [grass wiki](http://grasswiki.osgeo.org/wiki/GRASS_and_Shell)